# Change minimum heap size of executor in spark on yarn

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I want to change the initial/minimum heap size of my executors while running spark on yarn. Right now it throws the following exception,

> java.lang.Exception: spark.executor.extraJavaOptions is not allowed to alter memory settings

I am using the following `--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Xms4096m"` while running my spark-shell.

I am using spark 1.6.0. Greatly appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3):

A bit about `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions` from the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/configuration.html)

> Note that it is illegal to set Spark properties or heap size settings with this option. Spark properties should be set using a SparkConf object or the spark-defaults.conf file used with the spark-submit script. Heap size settings can be set with spark.executor.memory.

Try this `--conf "spark.executor.memory=4g"`

Comment: this gives me a static allocation of 4g on the executor with an -Xmx of 4g but i would want to set my Xms as well.

Comment: I believe heap size is fixed for executors in spark. In java terms, `spark.executor.memory=4g` is equivalent to setting both Xms and Xmx to 4g

Comment: I guess not because my yarn executor logs seem to start of at around 192m and keeps increasing there on.

Comment: That's interesting because the UI shows the full amount of memory allocated for the executors once they start. Not sure what to make of this